# When should I fetch data in update lifecycle of react?

Tags: reactjs, fetch

For example , I want to fetch data when click a button . where should I put my fetch function , I
usually put my fetch function in handler function .

```
// in my component
async handleButton(){
    if(!this.state.data){
        let data = await fetchFunction();
        this.setState({
          state_data : data    
        });
    }
}

render(){
    <button onClick={this.handleButton}>fetch data</button>
}
```

but in react , lifeCycle provide componentDidUpdate to fetch data . below is content in react doc describing componentDidUpdate.

*This is also a good place to do network requests as long as you compare the current props to previous props (e.g. a network request may not be necessary if the props have not changed).*

And I think that doc is mean I should write like this?

```
// in my component
handleButton(){
    if(!this.state.data){
       this.setState({
         need_fetch_data : true    
       });
    }
}
async componentDidUpdate(){
   if(this.state.need_fetch_data && !this.state.data){
      let tmp = await fetchFunction();
      this.setState({
          data : tmp;
      })
   }
}

render(){
    <button onClick={this.handleButton}>fetch data</button>
}
```

and I think that second way will render one more time than first method . So it is not ok .

thank for any answer !!

Comment: Depends, both make sense for their use-case. Trigger data fetch in handler if you want to fetch in response to a specific event. Trigger data fetch in `componentDidUpdate` if you want to fetch in response to state/props update.